# Calculating the seconds a face is visible

Tags: python, opencv

I have used the following code to detect faces and to assign id to each of the faces.

```
for face_no, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(detections):
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.putText(frame, str(face_no), (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,
                .7, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

How do I find out the number of seconds the face is visible in camera and display it? While developing iOS Apps, we have NSTimer to do this but how can I do this in python?

Comment: the module time has time.clock() and may help you with that. Just add a time to each of the faces, and when the face disappears you check the current time, and compare it with the initial time of the face.

Comment: can u please provide a short code?